# ERROR : actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java

```
class A1
{
    static int count=0;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello guys");
        if(count>0)
            main();

    }
}
```

Here i am getting  error that  actual and formal argument lists differ in length but when condition check condition is false then why it is executing the main() and says that actual and formal argument lists is differ .

Comment: If you're getting a compiler error, your code isn't running at all.

Comment: How many arguments does `main()` have? How many are you passing it?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a compiler error because `main` takes an array of `String`.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    System.out.println("Hello guys");
    if(count>0) {
        main(args); // <-- String[] args.
    }
}
```

Will fix your compiler error. And since `count == 0` that should just print

```
Hello guys
```

If `count > 0` it would be an infinitely recursive loop that would eventually end with a stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Your `main` method is expecting a string array.

look at the method signature:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
```

When you invoke `main` you need to pass the correct parameters to it.

```
       main(args);
```

However, if you wanted to create your own array of strings, you could do:

```
    String[] array = new String[args.length];

    if(count>0)
        main(array);
```

http://ideone.com/n2GMWw